# macvim shortcut ( and in general)

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, macvim

In my quest to understand how to indent & unindent on MacVim using elegant shortcuts that are built-in... I couldn't figure how.

The following links explain that <kbd>></kbd> <kbd><</kbd> keys will be handy, but none work on my keyboard, hence I wanted to clarify if these keys are something other than visible on the physical macbook, but no explanations are found.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332340/indenting-a-bunch-of-lines-in-vim
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235839/indent-multiple-lines-quickly-in-vi

Please can someone give me more guidance?

Comment: Are you holding shift while pressing these keys?

Comment: I see,, so `shift` + `<`+`<` or `shift` +`>`+`>` gives 8 movements

Comment: Did this solve your problem?(I'll post an answer with this if it did)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hold the shift key then double-press either <kbd>></kbd> or <kbd><</kbd> to indent/unindent.